# What's going on in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This loop is from a solution for a freeCodeCamp [challenge](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/smallest-common-multiple/). I don't understand how it works -- what does decrementing `i` do? I'm totally clueless. Any help understanding would be greatly appreciated.

```
for (var i = arr[0]; i >= arr[1]; i--) {
  newArr.push(i);
}
```

Here's the full solution the for loop is from:

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  // Sort array from greater to lowest
  // This line of code was from Adam Doyle (http://github.com/Adoyle2014)
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });

  // Create new array and add all values from greater to smaller from the
  // original array.
  var newArr = [];
  for (var i = arr[0]; i >= arr[1]; i--) {
    newArr.push(i);
  }

  // Variables needed declared outside the loops.
  var quot = 0;
  var loop = 1;
  var n;

  // Run code while n is not the same as the array length.
  do {
    quot = newArr[0] * loop * newArr[1];
    for (n = 2; n < newArr.length; n++) {
      if (quot % newArr[n] !== 0) {
        break;
      }
    }

    loop++;
  } while (n !== newArr.length);

  return quot;
}

// test here
smallestCommons([1,5]);
```

Comment: Especially as a beginner, you're right to be confused here. This is poorly written code and as such it does not communicate its intent very well at all, which is why the comments are necessary. Well written code communicates intent with each and every line, using descriptive variable names and orthodox programming patterns. This contains neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand how it works -- what does decrementing i do ?

Here you're passing two values to your function as an array `[1,5]`

```
smallestCommons([1,5]);
```

Inside `function smallestCommons` first thing we are doing is sorting array in `descending order`

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
});                       // arr = [5,1]
```

Now we are creating a newArray

```
let newArr = [];
  for (let i = arr[0]; i >= arr[1]; i--) {
    newArr.push(i);
}
```

- Here `arr[0] = 5` and `arr[1] = 1`
- So initial value of i is `5` and your condition is `i >= arr[1]`
- We keep decreasing value of `i` untill it is less than `arr[1] which is 1`
- So `newArray` will have value `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`